# How to link multiple frameworks

Tags: ios, frameworks

I'm developing a `framework A` that need to call function from another already packed `framework B` without adding that `framework B` into `framework A` project but the application should be having it, i tried someway but it always cant found files during build.

I also tried Cocoapods but seems like it don't recognize the vendored framework and I can't import the header in the development pods

Hope someone can help me solve this :)

Comment: I think you should configure all your dependencies in your build target's `Build Phases`. You may consider adding the dependency on `Link Binary With Libraries`.

Comment: I tried this, but when i creating fat framework it seems to trying to include that framework inside and cause so many error

Comment: If that's the case, you should build that framework from source. Just edit the source if there are syntax errors.

Comment: I cant, the `framework B` is a already packed framework from third party that i cant edit :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is possible...if `framework A` needs `framework B`, you're going to need to package `framework B` into `framework A` somehow, or make it VERY CLEAR that the user of `framework A` needs to also include `framework B` on their own, which is usually not a preferred way of distributing frameworks.

Comment: Yes, the user of `Framework A` must include `Framework B`, since as i read packing an already packed framework into another framework is not a good idea, also i tried this way but when creating fat framework it always give error so i think this is the better way